# Converting a text to command

Tags: r

I would like to know if there’s a way to convert a text to a command and execute it. Here’s the concerned part of the script I’m working on:

```
Var_name<- as.character(data_list[1,1])

U4005
```

(`data_list` contains just names of vectors in a bigger dataframe called `vectors`)

```
Comm<-paste(Var_name,”<-“,”vectors$”,Var_name)

Comm

“U4005<-vectors$U4005”
```

Comment: Why do you need this?  If you explain what you wanted with an example dataset and expected result, it would be easier.

Comment: Why do you want to take this approach?

Comment: data_list contains names of vectors selected following a specific analysis (based on correlations), so the objective is to automatically create independent variables from the selected vectors.

Comment: with `eval(parse(text=...))` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should reconsider your approach. [Fortune 106](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf): "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."

Comment: @Roland, well, then, I guess I was actually right not to post it as an answer... thanks for the tip, I will keep it in mind next time I want to use parse() !

Comment: @CathG Just to avoid confusion: my comment was primarily directed to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
e <- "a <- 1"
eval(parse(text = e))
a
# [1] 1
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

This seems a strange thing to do, but I think you are better off using `assign` rather than creating "interactive" commands to parse.

```
assign(Var_name,vectors[[Var_name]])
```

This way you can loop over your names to pull things out quite easily. You just need to specify that it is the global environment to assign to.

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=letters[1:3])
ls()
[1] "x"
invisible(sapply(names(x),function(y) assign(y,x[[y]],.GlobalEnv)))
ls()
[1] "a" "b" "x"
a
[1] 1 2 3
b
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
```